# VBA Excel - Send to Compressed Zip Folder

Tags: vba, excel, zip

I'm looking for a code to zip the folders of a path specified in my cells(1,1).value

After googling i found vba codes to zip the files of a folder but they are using WinZip.

My office machine does not have a WinZip installed and we are restricted to use WinZip. Could anyone please help with this. I need to use the default zip (Right click -> Send to compressed ZIP folder)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Sub Zip_File_Or_Files()
    Dim strDate As String, DefPath As String, sFName As String
    Dim oApp As Object, iCtr As Long, I As Integer
    Dim FName, vArr, FileNameZip

    DefPath = Application.DefaultFilePath
    If Right(DefPath, 1) <> "\" Then
        DefPath = DefPath & "\"
    End If

    strDate = Format(Now, " dd-mmm-yy h-mm-ss")
    FileNameZip = DefPath & "MyFilesZip " & strDate & ".zip"

    'Browse to the file(s), use the Ctrl key to select more files
    FName = Application.GetOpenFilename(filefilter:="Excel Files (*.xl*), *.xl*", _
                    MultiSelect:=True, Title:="Select the files you want to zip")
    If IsArray(FName) = False Then
        'do nothing
    Else
        'Create empty Zip File
        NewZip (FileNameZip)
        Set oApp = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
        I = 0
        For iCtr = LBound(FName) To UBound(FName)
            vArr = Split97(FName(iCtr), "\")
            sFName = vArr(UBound(vArr))
            If bIsBookOpen(sFName) Then
                MsgBox "You can't zip a file that is open!" & vbLf & _
                       "Please close it and try again: " & FName(iCtr)
            Else
                'Copy the file to the compressed folder
                I = I + 1
                oApp.Namespace(FileNameZip).CopyHere FName(iCtr)

                'Keep script waiting until Compressing is done
                On Error Resume Next
                Do Until oApp.Namespace(FileNameZip).items.Count = I
                    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))
                Loop
                On Error GoTo 0
            End If
        Next iCtr

        MsgBox "You find the zipfile here: " & FileNameZip
    End If
End Sub
```

Powered by Ron De Bruin - http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s7/win001.htm

Answer (score 0):

I have found it helpful to make a couple of tweaks to make this more friendly for the user (which for this sort of thing is often myself).

1. Limit how long you're willing to wait for the file & message the user if that time limit was reached without success
2. Add a DoEvents so that you can ctrl+break to pause the code in case you want to inspect (otherwise - can sometimes have to crash Excel, in my experience)
3. Add a statusbar update so the user knows what's going on

```
Sub ZipTheFile(ByVal strPath As String, ByVal strFileNameXls As String, ByVal strFileNameZip As String)
    'Taken largely from  Ron De Bruin - https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s7/win001.htm
    'Create empty Zip File
    NewZip (strPath & strFileNameZip)

    'Copy the file in the compressed folder
    Set oApp = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
    oApp.Namespace(strPath & strFileNameZip).CopyHere strPath & strFileNameXls

    'Keep script waiting until Compressing is done (OR we waited more than 40 seconds...)
    On Error Resume Next
    i = 0
    Do Until oApp.Namespace(strPath & strFileNameZip).Items.Count = 1 Or i > 40  '<-- set how long you're willing to wait here
        Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))
        DoEvents
        Application.StatusBar = "Waiting for Zip - counter: " & i
        i = i + 1
        
    Loop
    On Error GoTo 0
    If i > 40 Then MsgBox "there seems to have been a problem putting the file into the zip foder. Check the zip at: " & strPath & strFileNameZip
End Sub

Sub NewZip(sPath) 'You need this sub-routine as well
'Create empty Zip File
'by Ron De Bruin - https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s7/win001.htm
'Changed by keepITcool Dec-12-2005
    If Len(Dir(sPath)) > 0 Then Kill sPath
    Open sPath For Output As #1
    Print #1, Chr$(80) & Chr$(75) & Chr$(5) & Chr$(6) & String(18, 0)
    Close #1
End Sub
```

STILL Powered by Ron De Bruin - http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s7/win001.htm